# QPlainTextEdit for single line of input

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt to write a database type program where the majority of inputs will be single lines, not documents of arbitrary length.

Do I understand correctly that QPlainTextEdit is the most appropriate widget for this kind of input?

If so, how do you set parameters for this kind of input? In particular:

Height to the right value to comfortably hold one line of text in the current font, instead of stretching to fill available space.

Enter/cursor-down keys move to next control instead of next line in the document.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at the [`QLineEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qlineedit.html) class.